# How to display multi-byte characters in Groovy?

Tags: java, json, groovy

This following code showing ?????, when I giving multi byte language Ex : Chinese

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def jsonObj = new JsonSlurper().parseText( '{ "name":"怎么样", "age": 23}')

println jsonObj.name

println jsonObj.age
```

Output :

```
???????

23
```

Do I need to do any encoding and decoding to process this ?

If Yes, how I need to pass that value as a Json argument to above ParseText method ?

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't just that your console can't handle the Chinese name? If you just put `println "怎么样"` does that work?

Comment: That's correct Jon. It works here, using eclipse & the grepconsole plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't a json issue at all. Json implementation here works with old good java 2 bytes unicode chars. Hieroglyphs aren't a problem for it. The problem is in your output encoding. Is it a Windows or Mac console?

Proof code:

```
def jsonObj = new JsonSlurper().parseText( '{ "name":"怎么样", "age": 23}')
Writer unicodeFileWriter = new OutputStreamWriter( new FileOutputStream("herogliph.txt"), "UTF-8");
unicodeFileWriter.write(jsonObj.toString());
unicodeFileWriter.close()
```

The resulting herogliph.txt contains a valid name.

Try something like this.

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
out.println(unicodeMessage);
```

Comment: Hi Les, Thanks for reply, When I run the above script, I got the output as  follow {age=23, name=Ã¦â‚¬Å½Ã¤Â¹Ë†Ã¦Â Â·}

Comment: It isn't a magical solution forcing "UTF-8" encoding in your terminal, you still need to figure out your output encoding and insert it instead "UTF-8". But this wouldn't help if the console just doesn't support hieroglyph chars. Or you could change your terminal encoding to "UTF-8". We can't help with it without details.

Comment: HI, Thanks Les,  it's working fine after changing Eclipse Text file settings to UTF-8, Windows - > Preferences - > General - >  Workspace , Changed Text file encoding from cp1252 to UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

As per the below API, there is a method where you may pass arguments to specify the Charset.

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html

Below method may be useful. Convert your text to byte array and use below method.

```
parse(byte[] bytes, String charset)
```

Another scenario that I can think of is that your source file is encoded using a charset which is not the default charset of your OS.

Answer (score 0):

As Jon Skeet commented: you need a unicode capable console (like the grep console for eclipse: http://marian.schedenig.name/projects/grep-console/) to correctly format your output.